# Waiting for finished Java-process

Tags: java, process

I have a java application (principal) that calls an executable jar:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(java -jar C:\\PFC\\maestro.jar)
p.waitFor();
```

maestro.jar is a Java application that creates 2 threads, and calls another executable jar (which Process variable is "b"). Then I wait for them like this:

```
    b.destroy();  //kill other executable jar that is called
    manejadora.join();  //thread finished
    controlador.join();  //thread finished
    System.out.println("all finished");
```

maestro.jar runs CORRECTLY and it shows "terminated" on eclipse when I run it, so there are no problems.

When principal tries to run maestro.jar it runs correctly, but principal keeps waiting for maestro.jar on "p.waitFor()" when maestro.jar has already finished.

I don't understand why.

Could you give me some orientation about this? Thanks so much!

Comment: `Process.waitFor()` probably isn't broken, so, by elimination, it's most likely that the `java.exe` process for maestro.jar has kept running after all the work is done. You can easily verify this with Process Explorer. If this is the case, you have to figure out why the child JVM doesn't terminate, e.g. using JVisualVM to make a heap dump.

Answer (score 3):

This might be because the processes might be outputing stuff on the console which you are not consuming in a separate thread. Read this article for more info:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

The apache exec library does all these things for you nicely.. Use that library to fix your problem..

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Comment: I modified maestro.jar ---->now it doesnt call anything and it doesnt create the 2 threads.  It only shows  "System.out.println("all finished");".   And I run it with principal and it finished correctly.  So there is stuff on the console whithout consume (System.out.println sentences) and it finished correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I had to quit all "System.out.println();" sentences.

So i had to make a log in order to see program activity.

Thanks everybody :-)